# r - Prediction for new observation in knn

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to make an application which would predict prices based on users input. How can I predict the response for new values?

I have tried to do the following:
1. Add a new observation to the dataset
2. Train knn on all of the observations but the new one
3. Test knn on the new observation
But the prediction changes when I put different values of the response variable into the new observation so it doesn't seem to work.

Let's say the data has 100 observations of 7 variables.
This would be the code I have tried.

```
data <- rbind(data, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))  
prediction <- knn.reg(data[1:100,], test = dataset[101,],
data[1:100,]$response_variable, k = 8, algorithm="kd_tree")  
prediction$pred
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you have not defined `dataset`. I am guessing your code is meant to read:

```
dataset <- rbind(data, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))  
prediction <- knn.reg(dataset[1:100,], test = dataset[101,],
y = dataset[1:100,]$response_variable, k = 8, algorithm="kd_tree")  
prediction$pred
```

In any case, it seems that you are not supposed to include the response variable as a column in your training and test sets (I found this out by playing around with the `knn.reg` function.) So, if your response variable was the 7th column of `data` then you could do this instead

```
dataset <- rbind(data, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))  
prediction <- knn.reg(dataset[1:100,-7], test = dataset[101,-7],
y = dataset[1:100,]$response_variable, k = 8, algorithm="kd_tree")  
prediction$pred
```

For example, here is a test case with some made-up data.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:7, 700, replace=T), nr=100))
colnames(data)[7] <- "response_variable"
dataset <- rbind(data, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))  
prediction <- knn.reg(dataset[1:100,-7], test = dataset[101,-7],
dataset[1:100,]$response_variable, k = 8, algorithm="kd_tree")  
prediction$pred
```